# Calling a ".done" JS callback

Tags: clojurescript

I'm having some trouble with wrapping a JS library because I can't get a .done callback to work correctly.  In JavaScript the code would look like this:

```
db.values("inventory").done(function(item) {
  console.log(item);
});
```

So I tried a couple (very dirty) ClojureScript methods to translate this:

```
(defn log []
  (console/log "working?"))

(defn stock []
  (#(.done % log) (.values db "inventory")))
```

and

```
(defn stock []
  (js* "db.values('inventory').done(function(item) {
    console.log(item);
  })"))
```

but neither of these worked.  The error message is always something like: db.values(...).done is not a function

Are there any protocol extensions (or anything else) that could be used here to cover the JS callback?  Otherwise, can goog.async.Deferred somehow intercept the callback again?

Comment: Hi greenyouse1! Have you checked my response? It works fine in my computer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe this helps you!
I've done from node but it must work from browser with a little details

First for the demo code I've prepared a mock js lib to simulate yours (my_api.js)

This is my_api.js

```
console.log("my_api.js");
var db={};
db.item="";
db.values=function(_string_){
    db.item="loadign_"+_string_;
    return this;
};
db.done=function(_fn_){
    _fn_(db.item);

};

var api={hello:"ey ",  db:db};
module.exports=api;

// your pretended chain calls
//  db.values("inventory").done(function(item) {
//    console.log(item);
// });
```

And from clojurescript code ...

```
(ns cljs-demo.hello)

(defn example_callback []
  (let [my-api (js/require "./my_api") ; the api.js lib used for this example
        db (aget my-api "db") ; this is your db object
        my_fn (fn [item] ;this is your callback function
                (println "printing from clojurescript"  item)
                )
        ]
    (do
      (-> db (.values "inventory") (.done my_fn)) ;; calling your js in a similar way you want in js
      ;; or 
      (.done (.values db "inventory_bis") my_fn) ;; calling nested form in the standar lisp manner
      )
    ) 
  )
(set! *main-cli-fn* example_callback) ;default node function
```

And from console (node.js)

```
node your_output_node.js
```

And you'll obtain

```
printing from clojurescript loadign_inventory
printing from clojurescript loadign_inventory_bis
```

Good Luck,

Juan

Comment: Sorry I forgot to check Stack Overflow for a few months :p.  The problem I was having ended up being a JS library that I was working with. I'm marking your answer as correct though since this would work in a normal situation. Thanks for the help and sorry for my extreme slowness!